# Grep with regex from file in bash script without inclusion of more folders

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file containing various paths such as:

```
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file1.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file2.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file3.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/moreFiles/anotherFile.txt
/home/user/Desktop/text/prettyFile.txt
```

And I receive a input from user that contains the directory, such as:

```
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/
```

And I usually save this expression into regex to find all the files in the directory by grep. However, if the folder has more folders, it includes them as well, but I want to only include the files in the directory that was entered by the user. My desired output is should be this:

```
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file1.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file2.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file3.txt
```

But it keeps including

```
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/moreFiles/anotherFile.txt
```

which I don't want and I need to do it inside a bash script.

Comment: could you add the command you tried to question.. the downvote you've got is probably because of that..

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: What is Folers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep` command to get just the files directly under given path skipping sub-directories:

```
s='/home/user/Desktop/Bash/'
grep -E "$s[^/]+/?$" file
```

```
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file1.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file2.txt
/home/user/Desktop/Bash/file3.txt
```

Comment: Note that if `file` contains the name of sub-directories too, this method would return these names as well, e.g,  `/home/user/Desktop/Bash/moreFiles/`. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `grep` command cannot differentiate between files and directories. For that one needs to run `find` command with `-type f` or else loop through all found entries and check with `-f`